# Java Socket.Connect not throwing exceptions

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

My code checks if a given proxy is working or not and returns the type. In the function where I check if the proxy is HTTP or not, the Socket.Connect method doesn' throw any exception if the Proxy is dead.
This function is executed by a ExecutorService in a CachedThreadPool.
This is the function:

```
private CheckResponse checkHttp(MyProxy p) {

    try {

        SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(p.getIp(), p.getPort());
        Proxy proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
        Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        socket.connect(ProxyChecker.dest, Data.CHECK_TIMEOUT);  
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        socket.close();

        return new CheckResponse(false, elapsedTime);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return new CheckResponse(true, 0);

    }

}
```

Debugging I found that the program, after the socket.connect method, goes in the runWorker method in the ThreadPoolExecutor class and loops forever.

```
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
    Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
    Runnable task = w.firstTask;
    w.firstTask = null;
    w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
    boolean completedAbruptly = true;
    try {
        while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
            w.lock();
            // If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
            // if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
            // requires a recheck in second case to deal with
            // shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
            if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
                 (Thread.interrupted() &&
                  runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
                !wt.isInterrupted())
                wt.interrupt();
            try {
                beforeExecute(wt, task);
                Throwable thrown = null;
                try {
                    task.run();
                } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Error x) {
                    thrown = x; throw x;
                } catch (Throwable x) {
                    thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
                } finally {
                    afterExecute(task, thrown);
                }
            } finally {
                task = null;
                w.completedTasks++;
                w.unlock();
            }
        }
        completedAbruptly = false;
    } finally {
        processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
    }
}
```

No Execeptions are thrown, I cant't get the problem. Why?

Comment: What does your proxy do? What kind of exception do you expect to identify the server as a proxy? Are you sure that your proxy does react to your try to `connect`? Maybe you should try to connect with a second parameter, the timeout to not wait forever if he doesn't react?

Comment: In the socket.connect() method I pass two parameters: ProxyChecker.dest is a blank web site to test the connection, and Data.CHECK_TIMEOUT is a custom final int set to 5000, so 5 seconds of maximum wait, but after 1 or 2 seconds my programs run in the method said above and loops forever in the while.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your use of the ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @NiklasP
I create Executors with:
    public static final ExecutorService proxyCheckers = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Then in my code I start "ProxyChecker" for every proxy I want to check:
    proxyCheckers.submit(new ProxyChecker(proxies));

Then, inside ProxyChecker (extends Runnable) I use the method above to check if the proxy is HTTP.

But now I discovered that in every function I use Sockets they doesn't work. The program stops working going into an infinite loop.