# No exception thrown when failing to connect as client to server

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

Consider the following code:

```
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8060;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {

        if (success)
            Log.d("CONNECTION", "Success!");
        else
            Log.d("CONNECTION", "Fail...");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute();
    });
}
```

When I successfully connect to the server, "Success!" gets logged in the debug window and communication works fine! However, when I cannot connect to the server for various reasons (Not connected to the internet, server is offline, etc.) I should be presented with "Fail..." in the debug window, however, nothing gets shown... Not even an exception. While using breakpoints, it stops completely after `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT)` and does not iterate anywhere. It just stops... No exception gets logged nor caught. I need the app to notify if I could not connect to the server because the fact that nothing happens alone is not enough and raises more questions. After doing research through various threads with misleading questions and confusing answers... I'm stuck.

---

Thread #1
[Socket does not throw an exception though he can’t connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718450/socket-does-not-throw-an-exception-though-he-can-t-connect)

Thread #2
[Java Socket.Connect not throwing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998641/java-socket-connect-not-throwing-exceptions)

- I've tried running on both emulator and physical device. Both are working fine on successful connection and carry on with regular work, but behave exactly the same (as explained) when failing to connect.
- I've created the Socket object without arguments and called .connect afterwards, but I get the same results.
- I've included INTERNET permission inside the manifest

---

The rest are senseless and misleading... Allow me to boil it down:

- I am not failing to connect to the server when conditions are met (Server is online, connected to the internet, etc.)
- Server-client communication works flawlessly and has nothing to do with this thread
- I don't want the whole code to stop at `new Socket(...)`, I want to log that there has been an exception and print it. No exception gets thrown when the connection has failed and I need to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the server or route/firewall is not just dropping packets instead of RST per policy and you're seeing a normal wait for a TCP connection timeout?   If the debugger "just stops", it is blocking - this is completely consistent with that picture.

Comment: Does it actually have anything to do with it? The server is running on PC and has nothing to do with my issue here. If It's offline, then obviously it would have no impact on this.

Comment: That's not obvious at all.  If SYN packets are just being dropped by your network when the server is down, or a firewall is dropping them, then of course you will see blocking until the connection times out.   Have you let it run a minute or two every to see if it times out?

Comment: Ah, yes I have. The .connect method also provides a third argument for the timeout in milliseconds. However, with or without myself specifying the timeout, nothing happens after waiting...

Comment: This appears to be the emulator bug described in your first link.

Comment: So, now I'm using my local wireless ipv4 and it gives me timeout after like ten seconds or how many milliseconds I specify as the second argument. I can't tell you why I got no timeout after waiting for like two minutes with `127.0.0.1`, but now I've tried it out on different devices in real life and emulators and got everything working fine.